# Command Button not saving!

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, commandbutton

The command button on my Visualforce page is not saving edits to the record.  Any help is appreciated!

Visualforce Pg:

```
<apex:page action="{!redirectToPartnerships}" extensions="EditExtensions"
           standardController="PartnershipRequest__c">
    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageBlock title="Research Request Edit">
            <!--<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/> 
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>  -->
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Request Overview (Completed by 
                      Requestor)">
                <apex:inputField value="{!requestRecord.Name}"/>
                <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!requestRecord[f.fieldPath]}"
                                     required="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}"/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class EditExtensions {

    public string getRequestId { get; set; }
    public PartnershipRequest__c requestRecord { get; set; }
    public pageReference redirectReference;

    public yc_PartnershipEditExtensions(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        requestRecord = (PartnershipRequest__c) controller.getRecord();
        this.getRequestId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
        this.requestRecord = getRequest();
        this.redirectReference = null;
        //  requestRecord = [select DataTool__c, Agency__c, Client__c,
        Description__c, DesiredDueDate__c, PriorityRanking__c, ImpactCategory__c
        from PartnershipRequest__c where id=:getRequestId];
    }

    private PartnershipRequest__c getRequest() {
        String query = 'SELECT ';
        for (Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()) {
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
        }
        query += 'Id, Name FROM PartnershipRequest__c WHERE id=:getRequestId';
        //query += this.getRequestId;
        System.debug(Database.query(query));
        return Database.query(query);
    }

    public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
        Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypeMap =
                Schema.SObjectType.PartnershipRequest__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        System.debug('reqrec' + this.requestRecord);
        if (this.requestRecord.RecordTypeId == recordTypeMap.get('General Request').getRecordTypeId()) {
            //general request
            return SObjectType.PartnershipRequest__c.FieldSets.General_Request.getFields();
        } else if (this.requestRecord.RecordTypeId ==
                recordTypeMap.get('Troubleshooting Data Vendors').getRecordTypeId()) {
            //troubleshooting data vendors
            return
                    SObjectType.PartnershipRequest__c.FieldSets.Troubleshooting_Data_Vendors.getFields();
        } else if (this.requestRecord.RecordTypeId ==
                recordTypeMap.get('Sandbox').getRecordTypeId()) {
            //sandbox
            return SObjectType.PartnershipRequest__c.FieldSets.Sandbox.getFields();
        } else if (this.requestRecord.RecordTypeId == recordTypeMap.get('Partnerships').getRecordTypeId()) {
            //if field type is partnerships, use existing VF pages for Create / Edit / View (making the return below invalid. There are no field sets being used here.)
            //return
            SObjectType.PartnershipRequest__c.FieldSets.Partnerships.getFields();
            System.Debug('is this working?');
            //redirectReference = redirectToPartnerships();
            return SObjectType.PartnershipRequest__c.FieldSets.Troubleshooting_Data_Vendors.getFields();
        }

        //System.debug(this.requestRecord.RecordTypeId);
        return SObjectType.PartnershipRequest__c.FieldSets.Troubleshooting_Data_Vendors.getFields();
    }

    public PageReference redirectToPartnerships() {
        Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypeMap =
                Schema.SObjectType.PartnershipRequest__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        if (this.requestRecord.RecordTypeId ==
                recordTypeMap.get('Partnerships').getRecordTypeId()) {
            system.debug('redirect to partnerships');
            PageReference redirectRef = new


                    PageReference('https://c.cs21.visual.force.com/apex/PartnershipRequest_EditVF?
                    id=' + this.getRequestId);
                    redirectRef.setRedirect(true);
            return redirectRef;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wnich command? What do you mean by "no saving"? Are there errors? We need details...

Comment: can you add an `<apex:pageMessages/>` tag to your page? It should surface any errors that might be thrown by the standard controller

Comment: no errors, when I update a field and click the "Save" button, the changes are not committed.

Comment: See my 2nd comment above....

Comment: @SebastianKessel Don't worry, I got this one. Give me a min.

Answer (score 2):

The "save" function you're using is attached to the StandardController. However, the record you're attaching everything to is *not* the record in the standard controller. Your problems start here:

```
    requestRecord = (PartnershipRequest__c) controller.getRecord();
    this.getRequestId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
    // This is **not** from the standard controller
    this.requestRecord = getRequest();
```

Instead, you'll want to build your query and *copy* the values from the query to the standard controller record, *or* use the addFields method to load the necessary data.

---

```
public yc_PartnershipEditExtensions(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    String[] fields = new String[0];
    for (Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()) {
        fields.add(f.getFieldPath());
    }
    // This is not legal in unit tests, so skip...
    if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        controller.addFields(fields);
    }
    // now load record...
    requestRecord = (PartnershipRequest__c) controller.getRecord();
    getRequestId = requestRecord.Id;
}
```

Everything else should be okay from here.

Comment: I've tried updating the class with you code snippet and receive the following error: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: PartnershipRequest__c.Name

Comment: @FWSFDC Because of how your VF is written, you'll need to also add the Name field.

Comment: Not sure I follow?  Where would the Name field have to be specified in the Visualforce page@ @sfdcfox

Comment: @FWSFDC You can just add the Name field to the fields list.

Comment: do you mean add the Name field to the field set? there is no fields list in the VF page or Apex Class @sfdcfox

Comment: @FWSFDC `String[] fields = new String[] { 'Name' };`